# Convergence in measure, almost everywhere and almost uniformly.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to find counterexamples for this:

- $f_n\to f$ in measure implies $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly.
- $f_n\to f$ in measure implies $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere.

I proved that almost uniformly implies almost everywhere, so it suffices to show a counterexample for the second point. I mean, to show a sequence such that $f_n\to f$ in measure but $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ almost everywhere.

I know that the sequence of functions of the form $f_n=\chi_{A_n}$, where $\mu(A_n)\to 0$, converges to $0$ in measure. So I wanted to find $A_n$ such that $f_n$ doesn't converge to zero a.e.

Any hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1]$ and $$ \begin{align*} A_1 &:= \bigg( \frac{1}{2},1 \bigg] \\ A_2 &:= \bigg( 0, \frac{1}{2} \bigg] \\ A_3 &:= \bigg( \frac{3}{4}, 1 \bigg] \\ A_4 &:= \bigg( \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \bigg] \\ \vdots & \end{align*}$$

Comment: isn't it true that $\{x:\chi_{A_n}(x)\to 0\}=(0,1)$?

Comment: @Sandor: No.  In fact, $\{x:\chi_{A_n}(x)\to 0\}=\emptyset$.  For every $x$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x \in A_n$ (draw yourself some pictures to see how the sets $A_n$ march back and forth across the unit interval, infinitely many times).

Comment: Oh, you're right. I see it now. Thank you.